# Port forwarding in mac for local angular development

Tags: javascript, angularjs, macos, proxy, port

I have an AngularJS app running locally on port `8283` for development, and a python app running on port `8000`. Here is an example of an Angular method:

```
signIn: function (login, password, anon) {
        return $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/api/auth/login',
          data: $.param({'login': login, 'password': password, 'anon': anon}),
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function (response) {
          UserModel = response.data;
          serializeToSession();
          $rootScope.$broadcast('sign_in');
          return UserModel;
        }).then(() => updateUserTimezone());
      },
```

However, to run in localhost, I have to change:

```
   url: '/api/auth/login',
=> url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login',
```

Is there a way to do port forwarding on a mac, so that I can leave the url as is, and, for example, redirect requests at `/api/` to port 8000 instead of 8283? (Note I can do this fine on linux, but figuring out how to do this locally for development on a mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `System Preferences` and click on `Network`.

Inside `Network`, click on `Advanced` and navigate to `Proxies`. Check the `Web Proxy (HTTP)` box. Here you can enter a web proxy server + port and optionally enter a username and password.